# ESXi Virtualization server hardware

Tags: vmware-esxi, hardware

I am currently in the process of selecting hardware for a homelab ESXi server. My requirements are running around 30 virtual machines simultaneously with a GNS3 Cisco backbone running in the background.

As I've never really paid interest in server hardware I'm having a hard time selecting the best components for the server. I was lookin at AMD's Opteron series (as they seemed more friendly for my wallet) but on the other hand they don't seem to fare very well in tests against Xeons and even regular i7's. Besides that, the G34 Socket for the 6100/6200/6300 series are hard to come by here.

RAM wise I was looking at around 32 to 64GB. Power supply around 750 Watts. Also; Do I need to have an external GPU to power the VM's?

Questions, questions... Anyone that has some good input?

Comment: We don't do capacity planning or home use.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not supposed to post this here? Because in that case I'll take it down.

Comment: No, we're very clear about our requirements - anyway just stick to VMWare's HCL.

Comment: Hasn't been updated in a while, but do see: http://www.vm-help.com//esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php

Answer (score 1):

Some might say that SuperUser would be a better place to post this one.

However, to lend some assistance, ESX(i) *typically* works your RAM harder than your CPU.  Having said this, multiple cores are necessary - unless your ESXi guests aren't doing much.  Also, fast disk is important, otherwise you'll find disk I/O being a bottle neck.

To summarise:

- Invest in RAM over CPU
- Consider disk I/O next
- Have multiple cores available (quad-core i5 will probably be fine)

External GPU... as in Graphical Processing Unit?... definitely not.

Comment: Was doubting between SU and SF but the ESXi made me come here. Alright that is a helpful comment. Seeing as fault tolerance doesn't have top priority I suppose a RAID0 setup using a few SATA disks would suffice?

Comment: RAID1 man, RIAD1 for ESXI OS.

Comment: Fault tolerance... how precious are your VMDKs?